# LibreOffice Calc: overriding hide-if-zero for individual cells?

Tags: format, libreoffice, cells, zero, calc

I'm using LibreOffice Calc version 5.0.2.3.

I have my spreadsheet configured to hide zero values. However, for a small number of individual cells on this spreadsheet, I want to override the default behavior and explicitly show the zeros.

I can't find any formatting directives which enable this override behavior. Is there any way to override this hide-if-zero default on a cell-by-cell basis?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no feature to change view settings on a per-cell basis. There are different workarounds, depending on your data:

- If the zero values that should be visible are entered manually, you could enter them as text (with a leading apostrophe: `'0`). "Text zeros" aren't affected by the view settings to hide zero values. Pros: easy to implement; cons: restricted to manually-entered content.
- If the "visible" zero values are results of calculation, you will have to enable zero values generally, and hide zero values using cell styles where they shouldn't appear.

You can hide zero values using cell styles, since custom number styles may contain up to three sections, allowing different rules for positive / negative / zero values. For example, the following format code will hide a zero value, but it will display positive / negative integers: `#,###.00;-#,###.00;` (*please note that in my localisation, a point `.` is used as thousands separator*)